# Trying to import scikit-learn for mac

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn

I have attempted to install scikit-learn for python but I cannot get it to work. I have a mac, I installed anaconda and have read and tried many terminal lines of code. When I type `import sklearn` in the python IDE,  I get this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

When I try and type this code in the terminal, `pip3 install scikit-learn`,
I get this error:

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/bn/47m2pfjs7kq1v6klb5drql1h0000gn/T/pip-build-hqgq3wg4/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bn/47m2pfjs7kq1v6klb5drql1h0000gn/T/pip-kp1bl91n-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bn/47m2pfjs7kq1v6klb5drql1h0000gn/T/pip-build-hqgq3wg4/scikit-learn/
```

Comment: What "Python IDE" are you using. Have you tried `import sklearn` in a terminal session? I have a suspicion you are using IDLE, which is using your system Python interpreter, and you should be using the interpreter that comes with anaconda.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am using IDLE, which should still work, right?

Comment: It depends if you are using the IDLE that corresponds to the interpreter that you installed sklearn for...

Comment: xcode-select --install

Answer (score 0):

First, try to check which python you are you using

```
$ which python
```

it should print out something like this

```
/Users/youruser/anaconda/bin/python
```

Then make sure that is installed, check the list using:

```
$ pip list
```

If it is not installed use, as Robert says, conda install:

```
$ conda install scikit-learn
```